# How to read from a file line by line?

Tags: c++

I have a problem. I want to read each line from 'lol.txt'. What I have so far doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream file("lel.txt", ios::app);
ifstream file2("lol.txt");

//string write;
//getline(cin, write);
//file << write << "\n";
//file.close();
//}

string;
file2 >> read;
getline(cin, read);
cout << read;
}
```

Thanks!

P.S.: I am using Ubuntu and Code::Blocks.

Comment: You do know about loops? And you're reading a line from `std::cin` and not the file (from which you only read a "word").

Comment: @bbarnhart, I have read some questions and answers but none seem to be working for me.

Comment: First you are trying to read from file2 and then from cin (std input stream)? Also your main should return something.

Comment: @Itachi If there is no explicit return from `main`, the compiler adds an implicit `return 0;`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Didn't know about it. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: You said "each". You didn't do any "each".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes I know I didn't. If I could have done it I wouldn't have posted this question.